# employees informations.tpl prestashop

Tags: list, controller, smarty, prestashop

My problem:
I need to make an employee list in

> admin\themes\default\template\controllers\products\informations.tpl:
>
> http://darkplace.pl/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1111111111.png

So i pasted code in:

> \override\classes\Product.php

```
<?php
class Product extends ProductCore
{
public static function getEmployees()
{
  return Db::getInstance()->executeS('
   SELECT `id_employee`, `firstname`, `lastname`
   FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'employee`
   WHERE `active` = 1
   ORDER BY `lastname` ASC
  ');
}

}
?>
```

&&

> admin\themes\default\template\controllers\products\informations.tpl :

```
<select name="id_employee_forward" style="vertical-align: middle;">
 <option value="-1">{l s='-- Choose --'}</option>
 {foreach $employees as $employee}
  <option value="{$employee.id_employee}"> {Tools::substr($employee.firstname, 0, 1)}. {$employee.lastname}</option>
 {/foreach}
 <option value="0">{l s='Someone else'}</option>
</select>
```

It is not working 
I presume that i need to induce this code somewhere.

```
$employees = Product::getEmployees();
```

But hell will freeze before i figure it out by myself. So there it is. Quest 4 the best. 
**Please help me !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the data using smarty, from your screenshot it looks like you need to do this in the file AdminProductsController.php located in /controllers/admin/

You would achieve this with the following code.

`$this->context->smarty->assign("employees", Product::getEmployees());`

I would place this code in the function `renderForm()`

Comment: Thank You master programator. It worked like a charm. U R AWESOME!